# AssetBundle (DLC) data load to Android phone at runtime [UNITY]

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, download, loading, assets

I'm using Asset Browser of Unity. I want to reduce my game. So I should make Asset Bundle(DLC) and when i click download button in phone, datas will download and load to phone as permanantly, it will download at once, after that user can play as offline. I builded my data in Asset Browser. how can i load it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to build the asset bundles (with Asset bundle browser) and put them in a server that is publicly accesible. You need to use UnityWebRequest in your game to download your assetbundle from the server.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html

Or you can use Unity Asset Bundle Manager ***(EDIT: Looks like Unity removed it from the asset store)***

However, I have found this awesome tool, that I am actually using too, and it does a way better job. Just read the README, it is pretty straightforward. You just have to set the URL of your bundles, and then download bundles by specifying their name.

https://github.com/SadPandaStudios/AssetBundleManager

Comment: I downloaded the asset that your recommended. Well, is this enough attach "Example1.cs" to any gameobject? or I have to write another class?

Comment: You will probably need to write your own to handle assetbundles based on your specific logic. But if you just want to download an asset bundle (the script does not do anything else, it is just an example) then you can use it. But you have to replace the URL and put the one that contains your asset bundles
`abm.SetBaseUri("https://www.example.com/bundles");`

Comment: Also you need to change the bundle name here:
`abm.GetBundle("BundleNameHere", OnAssetBundleDownloaded);`. Then you have to write your own code to handle the assets in the bundle whatever way you need to

Comment: just download and loading to cache, there are nothing else. my Datas are "Sprites","Sounds" and "Animation". because these are highest size When the datas downloaded to game in Android (At Once), then these folders will place in game and the game will read these folders. Also the editor of this site marked existing thread but this is only Instantiate as GameObject. I don't want it any gameobjects. just data folders will load

Comment: I'm trying load my datas but giving error. Error downloading [/Users/****/Desktop/Unity Projects/***/AssetBundles/Android/Android]: [Cannot connect to destination host] there are two android folder but I have one android folder. I did not understand what's going on

Comment: When you build the asset bundles, you get an assetBundle folder, with one folder per platform you have built for. Your base URL (the one you should provide there) is the asset Bundles folder, not the android one. Also, to properly test it, you should upload them to a server, not use them locally

Comment: I fixed it. I wrote file:///Users... I think this don't decompress manifests. If decompressing where is the location? E.G my folders are sprites, sounds and animations folder in Assets/DLC. If I delete the folders at DLC folder, then the folders place in and it will read these?