# How I can test AssetBundle (DLC) locally on Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, assets, assetbundle

I'm trying to test some AssetBundles for the game that I'm currently working on. I want to use this because I don't want the game to take a lot of space. I still don't know how servers work and how to upload them over there. I was searching on how to do this and found some neat stuff over here: [AssetBundle (DLC) data load to Android phone at runtime [UNITY]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173173/assetbundle-dlc-data-load-to-android-phone-at-runtime-unity)
But it tells something about uploading to a server and stuff, but I want to test it locally. Any recommendation?

Following what Remy told me, my code looks like this:

```
public class LoadFromFileExample : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    string fileName = "planes";
    var myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName));
    if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
        return;
    }
    var prefab = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset< GameObject > ("andy");
    Instantiate(prefab);

    myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

But it shows the following error:  `Unable to open archive file: C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/myDLC/Assets/StreamingAssets/myassetBundle`

[This is the asset bundle name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8xzQ.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [AssetBundle.LoadFromFile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html).

This allows you to load in your assetbundle file from the local storage of the device. Meaning you don't have to upload/download them first.

it will look something like the following:

```
string fileName = "fooAssetBundle";//name of the assetbundle you want to load

var myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName));//Creates a filepath starting at the streamingAssetsPath and appends filename to it. 

var prefab = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>("MyObject");//Create a GameObject from the assetbundle
Instantiate(prefab);//instantiate the GameObject

myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);//Unload the assetbundle from memory as it isn't used anymore
```

The above example uses the `Application.StreamingAssetsPath` but this can be any path your desire like `Application.PersistentDataPath` or an external storage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm close for what I want to accomplish. I did what you suggested me and I get a error of: "Unable to open archive file: C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/myDLC/Assets/StreamingAssets/myassetBundle" and I don't know what is about. I even did a folder called "StreamingAssets" and put my asset bundle over there and still doesn't help :/

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in that localation? Like if you copy it in explorer you end up at the file, and there is a file anmed "myassetBundle?

Comment: That's the thing I'm worry about, I don't have a file name "myassetBundle" the asset bundle name is "planes" and I save the project and reload it and it keeps saying "myassetBundle"

Comment: I attached an image of the folder of assetBundles

Comment: inside "planes" it suppose to have 3 assets named: "andy", "jet" and "plane" .

Comment: what happens if you rename your "planes" file to "myassetBundle"? Does it load it then?

Comment: It's lowercase sensitive, so it only let me rename it "myassetbundle". I even change "filename" on the c# script to "myassetbundle" instead of "planes" and it still keeps appearing the same error: "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/myDLC/Assets/StreamingAssets/planes
UnityEngine.AssetBundle:LoadFromFile(String)" 
 " Failed to load AssetBundle!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LoadFromFileExample:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/LoadFromFileExample.cs:15)
"